# Trigger accordian function on page resize

Tags: jquery, mobile, resize, accordion

Is it possible to trigger the following code on a window resize. I basically need an accordion to kick in when the browser window is resized to under 660px, and the made null if over 660px.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion ul').slideUp(-100);
});


$(".accordion > li > p").click(function(){
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('.accordion ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});


$('.accordion ul:eq(0)').show();
```

I hope there is enough info here.

Thanks,

Mitch

Answer (score 1):

See this sample:

```
function DimensionaCatalogo() {
    var tamanho = $(window).width();

    if (tamanho <= 1024) { // iPad
        $("#Carrinho").hide();
    }
}
```

To intercept window resize use this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
     DimensionaCatalogo();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but am slightly confused as how to implement it, not sure if it is the Portugese or my lack of code knowledge. (Probably the later:) )

Comment: dimensionaCatalogo = ResizePage()

Comment: make your tests and adjustments in the $ (window). resize (function () 
that is triggered when the window is resized.